# Joomla - Add html code to BACKEND template manager of protostar

Tags: html, css, joomla

I am trying to make protostar template BACKEND more user friendly. I want to add a left sidebar with options such as "Fonts", "Layout", "..."  etc. I also would like to be able to style the backend options, fieldsets and fields.

Please note: This question is for the Joomla administrator backend and not for the front end site.

I know html and css well but I dont know where to override the backend template manager looks like some of the theme providers do. For example:

https://farm9.staticflickr.com/8609/16244287038_cdff31be92_b.jpg

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you look in the administrator/templates/isis folder you will find the default backend template. here you can edit the index.php file to suite your needs. I would make a copy of isis and rename it to something else and then activate it via the template manager in the backend. This way, when the site is updated your template wont be overwritten.

Comment: Thanks - the isis folder's  index.php is to modify the template "isis" itself. I am talking about changing the looks of ONE template within the "templates > my_template" folder. I dont want to edit ISIS template - You can see how template creators create templates that have a different look when we open it in template manager..